# gwt-user.jar with Java 11 - The package javax.xml.parsers is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml

Tags: java, gwt, java-module

I am trying to switch to GWT 2.10 and Java 11 (using Eclipse container for GWT and gradle for dependencies), but because some java packages are bundled in gwt-user.jar I get the error:

```
The package javax.xml.parsers is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
```

Searching the web, the solutions I found were either to repackage the gwt-user.jar by removing the packages or to turn my project into a module (which I don't see it recommended and also I don't know what implications/chain reaction has). Neither of these options seem good.

Is there an alternative to solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe the problem is specifically that you're using the "eclipse container" for GWT rather than Gradle. The JARs published to Central bundle much fewer third-party libs.

Comment: Hi, yes i just noticed today. Will try, thanks!

Comment: How to solve that? Didn't found a solution. THanks

Comment: I updated my gradle files to use the "com.google.gwt" dependencies for gwt-user.jar and gwt-dev.jar. I will post as answer in a few minutes...

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I solved my issue by getting the dependencies from com.google.gwt bundle. But I had a lot of issues here because I am using gwt material, which at that moment was also getting the "big jars" dependencies. So my gradle looks like this now:

```
//for Eclipse with GWT plugin (which creates the gwt classpath container):
classpath {
    ...
    containers GWT_CONTAINER //from my gradle properties - com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER/gwt-2.10.0
}

def gmdVersion = '2.6.0' //library GWT Material
def gwtVersion = GWT_VERSION//from my gradle properties file - 2.10.0
def gwtNamespace = 'com.google.gwt' //org.gwtproject in the future i think

api (group: "${gwtNamespace}", name: 'gwt-dev', version: GWT_VERSION)
api (group: "${gwtNamespace}", name: 'gwt-user', version: GWT_VERSION) 

api (group: 'com.github.gwtmaterialdesign', name: 'gwt-material', version: "${gmdVersion}") {
        exclude group:"${gwtNamespace}", module: "gwt-user"
        exclude group:"${gwtNamespace}", module: "gwt-dev"
        ...
    }

api (group: 'com.github.gwtmaterialdesign', name: 'gwt-material-jquery', version: "${gmdVersion}") {
        exclude group:"${gwtNamespace}", module: "gwt-user"
        exclude group:"${gwtNamespace}", module: "gwt-dev"
        ...
    }
api (group: 'com.github.gwtmaterialdesign', name: 'gwt-material-addins', version: "${gmdVersion}") {
        exclude group:"${gwtNamespace}", module: "gwt-user"
        exclude group:"${gwtNamespace}", module: "gwt-dev"
        ...
    }
```

Depending on each person's project structure, some other dependencies might also cause a similar issue, so if this doesn't work from the start, you need to check which other classes are imported from multiple dependency jars. Or, you can try to create a new project where you can simulate the error just for GWT related classes (just a simple new empty project where you configure just basic dependencies), then you try this solution and it should work.